# Authenticate private google cloud artifact registry from Tekton Pipeline

Tags: gradle, google-cloud-platform, build.gradle, tekton, google-artifact-registry

I have a local setup of Tekton Pipeline, which has task to clone and build application . The code base is on java so, clones the code from BitBucket and does a Gradle build.

**gradle.build**

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "artifactregistry://${LOCATION}-maven.pkg.dev/${PROJECT}/${REPOSITORY}"
    }
}
```

**gradle.properties**

```
LOCATION=australia-southeast2
PROJECT=fetebird-350310
REPOSITORY=common
```

I have set up a service account and passed it to the pipeline run

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: gcp-secret
  namespace: tekton-pipelines
type: kubernetes.io/opaque
stringData:
  gcs-config: |
    {
      "type": "service_account",
      "project_id": "xxxxx-350310",
      "private_key_id": "28e8xxxxx2642a8a0cd9cd5c2696",
      "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKcwggSjAgEAAoIBAQC3zOuPTogiZ2kU\nEYsGMCl4lUO48GSLOjOH1lwkQ76zxL\n0F6cfpV/8iwao/9IOqsmKoRPUZcQjqXFMEuCYJNhoScsn4TAYMNBeATVq+2JJ/5T\n2e7YfbbPVue9R36MfTwqDeI=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
      "client_email": "xxxxxx@xxxx-xxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
      "client_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
      "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
      "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
      "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/fetebird%40fetebird-350310.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    }
```

**service-account**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: service-account
secrets:
  - name: git-ssh-auth
  - name: gcp-secret
```

During the Gradle build, getting an exception as

```
> Could not resolve fete.bird:common:1.0.1.
2022-06-22T12:43:41.599990295Z          > Could not get resource 'https://australia-southeast2-maven.pkg.dev/fetebird-350310/common/fete/bird/common/1.0.1/common-1.0.1.pom'.
2022-06-22T12:43:41.606630129Z             > Could not GET 'https://australia-southeast2-maven.pkg.dev/fetebird-350310/common/fete/bird/common/1.0.1/common-1.0.1.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
```

[image]

```
implementation("fete.bird:common:1.0.1") is published on GCP artifact registry
```

In local development, the Gradle build is working file, because the service key is exported as environment variable `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="file-location.json"`

**Pipeline Run**

```
apiVersion: tekton.dev/v1beta1
kind: PipelineRun
metadata:
  name: run-pipeline
  namespace: tekton-pipelines
spec:
  serviceAccountNames:
    - taskName: clone-repository
      serviceAccountName: git-service-account
    - taskName: build
      serviceAccountName: gcp-service-account
  pipelineRef:
    name: fetebird-discount
  workspaces:
    - name: shared-workspace
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: fetebird-discount-pvc
  params:
    - name: repo-url
      value: git@bitbucket.org:anandjaisy/discount.git
```

Answer (score 0):

You mount that Service Account secret as volumeMount inside the pod and set an Environment Variable "export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="path to secret inside the pod" in pod /deployment definition.

Comment: Since the pot is created by the tekton task, I don't have access to the deployment defination, how can I export the credential